# boundingRectWithSize of NSMutableAttributedString returns wrong value when attributes added partially

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, nsattributedstring

I want to calculate a size of `NSMutableAttributedString` by using `boundingRectWithSize`.
It returns accurate value when all attributes are added for all range.
However, when I add partial range attribute (for example, partial color), it returns inaccurate value.

Here is an example.

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play
import UIKit

func makeSample(text text: String) -> NSMutableAttributedString {
    let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text)
    let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 5.0
    attributedString.addAttributes([
        NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "HiraKakuProN-W3", size: 14.0)!,
        NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle
        ], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: attributedString.length))

    return attributedString
}

func height(of attributedString: NSMutableAttributedString) -> CGFloat {
    let options = unsafeBitCast(
        NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesLineFragmentOrigin.rawValue |
            NSStringDrawingOptions.TruncatesLastVisibleLine.rawValue,
        NSStringDrawingOptions.self)
    return attributedString.boundingRectWithSize(CGSize(width: 100, height: CGFloat.max), options: options, context: nil).height
}


// one color string
let oneColorAttributedString = makeSample(text: "hello")
oneColorAttributedString.addAttribute(
    NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
    value: UIColor.blueColor(),
    range: NSRange(location: 0, length: oneColorAttributedString.length) // whole range
)
print(height(of: oneColorAttributedString)) // print 14.0 <- OK

// partial color string
let partialColorAttributedString = makeSample(text: "hello")
partialColorAttributedString.addAttribute(
    NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
    value: UIColor.blueColor(),
    range: NSRange(location: 0, length: 1) // first letter only
)
print(height(of: partialColorAttributedString)) // print 19.0 <- wrong value!!
```

How can I avoid this?
Are these configurations incorrect?